# document.write() and document.images[i].width fails in IE8!

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, html

I'm using `document.write()` just to debug some code and found some very strange behaviour in IE8. Is it me, or is this a bug?!

A page with just 4 `img` elements:

```
<img src="img/one.jpg" width="100" height="75" alt="1st Demo Image" title="">
<img src="img/two.jpg" width="100" height="75" alt="2nd Demo Image" title="">
<img src="img/three.jpg" width="100" height="75" alt="3rd Demo Image" title="">
<img src="img/four.jpg" width="100" height="75" alt="4th Demo Image" title="">
```

Looping through the `document.images` HTMLCollection to output the value of the width attribute for each image using `document.write()` (or `document.writeln()` it doesn't matter):

```
for (var i=0; i<document.images.length; i++) {
    document.writeln(i + ' - ' + document.images[i]['width']);
}
```

All browsers, except IE8, output 4 lines as expected. IE8, however, just outputs the 1st line, for the first image! Why?!

The loop is 'looping' OK. You can output the `width` attribute using an `alert()` and you get 4 alerts in IE8, but still only the first line is output using `document.write()`!

```
for (var i=0; i<document.images.length; i++) {
    document.writeln(i + ' - ' + document.images[i]['width']);
    alert(i + ' - ' + document.images[i]['width']);    // Alerts 4 times
}
```

The 'height' attribute is also a problem. Other attributes, however, like 'src', 'alt' and even undefined attributes like 'monkey' output OK; providing you *don't* have an `alert()` in the loop as well!

If you take `document.write()` out of the loop, append to a string inside the loop and only have 1 `document.write()` after the loop to output the string then that is OK.

It is also a problem accessing the width attribute via the NodeList... `document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].width` - same problem as above, only the first line is output!

Any ideas? Or is it just an 'IE8' quirk!?

**EDIT#1**

This code is *not* being run in an event, like `onload`. It is being run in a script element in the body of the page, whilst the page is being parsed. Yes, you cannot call `document.write()` in an event, hoping to influence the current document since document parsing will probably have completed and calling `document.write()` will implicitly open a new document.

This problem *only* manifests itself on IE8.
IE6, IE7, IE9 and all other browsers tested work as expected.

**EDIT#2 - Found the cause (but not the reason)**

Ok, I thought my test page was very simple - it appears it wasn't quite simple enough! I think I've found the cause (not the reason) of this problem, but unfortunately this is where it gets even weirder!

The problem appears to be if the script element producing the output is directly inside an element that is `display:block`. This does not have to be an element that is inherently a block-level element (like `div` or `pre`), but any element that is `display:block`! There must be no white-space between the block container and the script element.

So, this exact code (between the body tags) reproduces this problem in IE8:

```
<img src="img/one.jpg" width="100" height="75" alt="1st Demo Image">
<img src="img/two.jpg" width="100" height="75" alt="2nd Demo Image">
<img src="img/three.jpg" width="100" height="75" alt="3rd Demo Image">
<img src="img/four.jpg" width="100" height="75" alt="4th Demo Image">
<pre><script type="text/javascript">
// Only the first line is output in IE8, other browsers OK
for (var i=0; i<document.images.length; i++) {
    document.writeln(i + ' - ' + document.images[i]['width']);
}
</script></pre>
```

But, if you were to put just a single space after the opening `<pre>` tag the problem goes away (but you get an extra space in the output)!

And, this only seems to affect the `width` and `height` (numeric?) attributes!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your `document.write` clears the document (I'm [not sure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.open) if that's per spec or implementation dependent but that will invoke `document.open()` which will clear the document including images). So after the first `document.write()` call clears the document, there are no longer images, so when the loop continues to access `document.images[1]` the item is no longer available.

That explains why any other method works, since alerting, or concatenating a string won't clear the document.

Comment: I did wonder about this, but the `document.write()` is not in an event handler, it is in the body of the page before the document has been fully written. Outputting other attributes works OK. Outputting the `alert()` with the `document.write()` does produce 4 alerts, which it presumably wouldn't do if the first write() cleared the document?

Comment: @w3d, if the document isn't written yet you shouldn't be trying to access its internals yet...

Comment: This is test/debug code that appears before the closing `body` tag, so the DOM _should_ be complete enough for this code to work OK. In fact this doesn't appear to be a DOM issue at all. I've updated the question (Edit#2) with an exact scenario which appears to trigger this _phenomenon_. This only appears to affect IE8.

Answer (score 1):

The document will overwrite the contents of the body if it runs after onload of the document.

Try this:

```
var htm = [];
for (var i=0; i<document.images.length; i++) {
    htm.push(i + ' - ' + document.images[i]['width']); 
}

document.write(htm.join(''));
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I omitted that from my question initially. The code is not being run in an event. It is being run in the page whilst the document is being parsed. As mentioned in my question, if I concatenate a string in the loop and output that outside the loop with `document.write()` then it works also, but I like the array idea - thanks.